# How to change the rootviewcontroller to the third viewcontroller in a stack

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, rootviewcontroller

```
var window: UIWindow?



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

        let settingStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Setting", bundle: nil)
        let toDoListStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ToDoList", bundle: nil)
        let homeStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
        let eventListStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "EventList", bundle: nil)
        let activityStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Activity", bundle: nil)

        let settingVC = settingStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Setting") as! SettingViewController
        let toDoListVC = toDoListStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ToDoList") as! ToDoListViewController
        let homeVC = homeStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as! HomeViewController
        let eventListVC = eventListStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EventList") as! EventListViewController
        let activityVC = activityStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Activity") as! ActivityViewController

        let vcData: [(UIViewController, UIImage, UIImage)] = [

            (settingVC, UIImage(named: "SettingIcon")!, UIImage(named: "SettingSelectedIcon")!),
            (toDoListVC, UIImage(named: "ToDoIcon")!, UIImage(named: "ToDoSelectedIcon")!),
            (homeVC, UIImage(named: "HomeIcon")!, UIImage(named: "HomeSelectedIcon")!),
            (eventListVC, UIImage(named: "EventIcon")!, UIImage(named: "EventSelectedIcon")!),
            (activityVC, UIImage(named: "ActivityIcon")!, UIImage(named: "ActivitySelectedIcon")!)
        ]

        let vcs = vcData.map { (vc, image, selectedImage) -> UINavigationController in

            let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

            nav.tabBarItem.image = image.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
            nav.tabBarItem.selectedImage = selectedImage.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)

            nav.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 7, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)

            return nav
        }

        tabBarController.viewControllers = vcs
        tabBarController.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
        tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 19/255, green: 41/255, blue: 77/255, alpha: 1)

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 19/255, green: 41/255, blue: 77/255, alpha: 1)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

        window?.rootViewController = tabBarController

        print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)

        return true
    }
```

In the code shown above when the app runs the rootviewcontroller is the first view that was added to the stack. How would you change the rootviewcontroller to the HomeViewController without initializing the homeviewcontroller first.

Comment: When this code runs, the root view controller is the tab bar. Are you asking how to make the 3rd tab the initially selected tab?

Comment: @rmaddy yes I want the 3rd tab to be the initial view controller

Comment: You should [edit] your question to make that clear. Chris's answer below is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
```

after your line

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = vcs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change RootViewController anytime in following way

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let homeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController = homeViewController
```

Comment: Please read the comments below the question and also read the other answer.